My Anaconda Navigator wont launch from cmd or manually
yesterday, i uninstalled my anti virus and after that , the navigator is not launching any more.
i tried going to the script file and updating my conda and navigator.
however the navigator update gets stuck after some time.
i have tried, almost most solutions available, but none of the hit and miss are working.
conda update conda// works
conda update anaconda-navigator // this one gets stuck
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqtwebengine // both works .
jupiter opens up but anaconda navigator doesnot
i tried running navigator directly from script cmd.
C:\Users\sayan.anaconda\navigator\scripts> anaconda-navigator
it provides the following:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in 
from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in 
from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 27, in 
from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window_init_.py", line 52, in 
from anaconda_navigator.widgets.tabs.community import CommunityTab
File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\tabs\community.py", line 23, in 
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt' (C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageQt.py)
PS C:\Users\sayan.anaconda\navigator\scripts>

Finally after much tinkering, i found that my terminal was not updating the base environment which is why it was not launching.
The only way I solved it was to uninstall anaconda and reinstall it after which setting the path and activating the base did the trick for me.
setting up the path , if anyone needs can refer here
'Conda' is not recognized as internal or external command

Just my humble two-cents. All of a sudden, my Anaconda Navigator would not open on my Win 10 PC. Icon was no longer in Windows Start and it did not respond on Task Bar. I clicked it and it did nothing. It still shows in Control Panel Programs. I believe that the Windows 10 OS was responsible for this issue. The Win 10 User folder with Anaconda had all the files Hidden under the folder Properties. I also have Anaconda on Win 7 PC and it is working fine and the User folder is not Hidden. In Win 10 I accessed the folder with Anaconda, went to Properties, and un-checked the box for Hidden files. Now my Anaconda loads properly as it did before. Glad to have Win 7 for comparison.
